# code for onclick navbar item changes to active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navbar

I need to change the hover state of the navbar item to active state onclick.I do not know how to write the code for this bootsrap navbar as I cannot really access the links/ .Anything in jquery /javascript /php will be helpful.

MY HTML CODE:

```
<div class="navbar-inner">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">DETAILS</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>

</nav>
```

MY CSS CODE:

.navbar
        {

```
      margin: 10px;

    }

    .navbar.center .navbar-inner
     {

        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav 
    {

      float: none;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .navbar .nav > li > a, .navbar .nav > li > a:first-letter,
    .navbar .nav > li.current-menu-item > a, 
    .navbar .nav > li.current-menu-ancestor > a 
    {
      display:        inline;
      color:          white;                        
      font-family:    'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;
      font-size:      12px;
      padding:        10px;
      font-weight:    bold;
      letter-spacing: 2.5px;
      border: 2px solid transparent;




    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus 
    {

        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;  



    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus 
    {
        color: white;
        background: black;

        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: paste your javascript code please

Comment: post entire HTML code of navbar

Comment: I havent written any.I tried writing it but didnt work so removed it.

Comment: <nav class="navbar  center navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">

Answer (score 0):

This code is in jQuery, I hope this is enough to get you started with what you want to  do with your navbars. Good Luck!

```
//Click event handler for nav-items
$('.nav-item').on('click',function(){

  //Remove any previous active classes
  $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');

  //Add active class to the clicked item
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Did this code work for you because it is not working for me.my classes in css are big so can you be specific what exactly to write in the add and remove class

Comment: @AkshaySargar what do you mean by 'big'? You can change the active to your classname. It is just adding and removing classes to the item that has been clicked.

Answer (score -1):

This may be an old post, but I had the same problem as you, and the code snippet provided didn't work either. The solution I found was to add the code in a ready() function like that. Notice that i used a single `<script>` tag to include my jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.nav-item').on("click", function(){

$('.nav-item').removeClass('active');

$(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```